# Generating a deduplicated event stream without a window

Tags: esper

I'm trying to generate a stream of deduplicated events without specifying any window policy beyond that used for the deduplication. Using an `output first every` clause on my queries appears to have the desired effect, but not when those queries are inserting directly into a stream.

For the example given below, say that I'm trying to detect only the first honk from each car in a 4-hour window.

```
(define-event-type! "CarEvent"
   {:license_plate java.lang.String})

(define-event-type! "HonkEvent"
   {:volume java.lang.Integer}
   :supertypes #{"CarEvent"})

(define-variant! "HonkEventDeduplicated" "HonkEvent")

(define-statement! "context-IndividualCarContext"
  "create context IndividualCarContext partition by license_plate from CarEvent")

(define-statement! "populate-HonkEventDeduplicated"
  "context IndividualCarContext
   insert into HonkEventDeduplicated
   select * from HonkEvent
     group by license_plate
     output first every 4 hours")
```

However -- `select * from HonkEventDeduplicated` fires on every single honk event, even when the same car honks twice in a row.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `output first every` clause filtering, this can be done with the `std:firstunique` view:

```
(define-statement!
  "populate-HonkEventDeduplicated"
  "insert into HonkEventDeduplicated
  select * from HonkEvent.win:time(4 hours).std:firstunique(license_plate)")
```