# What term is used to describe a queuing/messaging system that acts upon one event after receiving several identical events?

Tags: message-queue, terminology

What term (or terms) is used to describe a queuing/messaging system that receives several identical events/messages over a period of time and "buffers" them so that only one is acted upon? In Javascript, for example, this is actually called "buffering" (only executing a particular function once in response to several events in a short time). And maybe "buffer/buffering" is the right term, but I'm wondering if there's a more appropriate term when the "system" is a messaging bus.

Comment: FYI,  this kind of deduplication is the kind of task a CEP system like Esper can handle easily. That said, it necessarily means retaining state (and managing the amount of that state); you need a bounded cache of recent events to compare against, so there are memory requirements involved. (Of course, you can set your window size to have fixed memory  usage, or a fixed time guarantee, but unless you know max throughput, you can't have both).

Comment: As described at [Is it OK to ask for a word choice on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277500/is-it-ok-to-ask-for-a-word-choice-on-stack-overflow), this question is off-topic -- not just here, but *anywhere* on the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Thank you for pointing out the prohibition on word choice questions, but I didn't see my question like that. I'm not looking for a word choice to describe a database field, etc., I'm looking for the term that describes something that I'm trying to research. Using "buffer" or even "deduplication", as you suggest, hasn't turned up anything on this topic. I feel certain that there are many implementations of such a system, and I'm hoping that using the right term will help me find information on them. But I'll definitely check out Esper, per you suggestion.

Comment: ...heh. Turns out I asked a question about how to do this in Esper (and ended up answering it myself) years ago: [Generating a deduplicated event stream without a window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310194/generating-a-deduplicated-event-stream-without-a-window). [Riemann](http://riemann.io/) similarly has primitives that make this kind of thing easy to construct (being an event-processing language oriented around alerting, suppressing duplicate alerts is very much a thing).

Comment: That said, if you look at the other duplicates to that meta question, they extend beyond "word choice", and into identification requests. [Are "what are this thing called?" questions on topic for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277508/are-what-is-this-thing-called-questions-on-topic-for-stack-overflow) is a bit more directly on-point.

Comment: ...see the time-window functions in http://riemann.io/api/riemann.streams.html; if you fold in duplicate events by eliminating them (think of reducer operation in map/reduce style), there you are.